# Mongodb find all dictionaries in a list that contains specific discipline_Name and extract individual data of that dictionary

Tags: python, database, mongodb, find, fetch

This is my data set. I have consumed a lot of time on this but cannot get the actual outcome I want. Please help me in finding my data
You can see the `JSON` below I want to extract all the disciplines that contain specific discipline_Name like discipline_Name: "Computer Science"
then I want to extract only those dictionaries that contain (discipline_Name: "Computer Science")
Also, tell me how to fetch individual data of that particular dictionary
I doing this in python
I have tried the following code but getting the actual output

```
import requests
import re
import json
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["FYP_DataBase"]
mycol = mydb["balochistan_uni"]
data = mydb.balochistan_uni.find({"disciplines.discipline_name":"Computer Science","disciplines.degree_Name":"BE"},{ '_id':0 ,"disciplines":1,"discipline.discipline_Name" :1, })
for d in data:
    print(d)
```

.........................................................

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b98e604c0c4d54a5016e646"),
    "uni_name" : "Balochistan University Of Engineering & Technology BUET, Khuzdar",
    "location" : "KHUZDAR P.O Box No. 89100 [BALOCHISTAN] ",
    "web_link" : "http://www.buetk.edu.pk ",
    "province" : "Balochistan",
    "category" : "Public",
    "disciplines" : [ 
        {
            "discipline_name" : "Civil",
            "degree_Name" : "BE",
            "duration" : "4 Years",
            "Fee_per_Year" : "NA",
            "admission_date" : "15-09-2018",
            "Last_Merit" : "50"
        }, 
        {
            "discipline_name" : "Computer Science",
            "degree_Name" : "BS",
            "duration" : "4 Years",
            "Fee_per_Year" : "NA",
            "admission_date" : "31-01-2018",
            "Last_Merit" : "NA"
        }, 
        {
            "discipline_name" : "Computer System",
            "degree_Name" : "BE",
            "duration" : "4 Years",
            "Fee_per_Year" : "NA",
            "admission_date" : "15-09-2018",
            "Last_Merit" : "NA"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b98e60dc0c4d54a5016e648"),
    "uni_name" : "Lasbela University Of Agriculture, Water And Marine Sciences, Uthal LUAWMS, Lasbela",
    "location" : "Lasbela ",
    "web_link" : "http://www.luawms.edu.pk ",
    "province" : "Balochistan",
    "category" : "Public",
    "disciplines" : [ 
        {
            "discipline_name" : "Agriculture",
            "degree_Name" : "BS",
            "duration" : "4 Years",
            "Fee_per_Year" : "15000",
            "admission_date" : "14-09-2018",
            "Last_Merit" : "NA"
        }, 
        {
            "discipline_name" : "Business Administration",
            "degree_Name" : "BBA",
            "duration" : "4 Years",
            "Fee_per_Year" : "15000",
            "admission_date" : "14-09-2018",
            "Last_Merit" : "NA"
        }, 
        {
            "discipline_name" : "Computer Science",
            "degree_Name" : "BS",
            "duration" : "4 Years",
            "Fee_per_Year" : "15000",
            "admission_date" : "14-09-2018",
            "Last_Merit" : "NA"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that a document owns multiple 'computer science' disciplines?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: Do you want to find all entries (universities) which have "discipline_name": "Computer Science" and "degree_Name": "BE" for a discipline? If a university offers "Computer Science" with degree "BS"  and "Agriculture" with degree "BE" should it be matched or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query:

```
mydb.balochistan_uni.find({
    "disciplines.discipline_name": "Computer Science",
    "disciplines.degree_Name": "BE"
})
```

retrieves all universities that have a discipline "Computer Science" and a degree "BE". Your query doesn't specify that it should be the discipline "Computer Science" with a degree "BE".

If you want to do that you have to match an element within the array `disciplines`. The query should look like this:

```
mydb.balochistan_uni.find({
    "disciplines": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "discipline_name": "Computer Science",
            "degree_Name": "BE"
        }
    }    
},
{
    "_id": 0, "disciplines": 1
})
```

Now this query will retrieve only universities where the discipline name is "Computer Science" and the degree name for "Computer Science" is "BE".

Please check the official [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-array/) of MongoDB for Array Query Operators.
When a field in MongoDB contains an array, you have to apply those operators.

Comment: its $elemMatch not working getting error 
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unknown top level operator: $elemMatch

Comment: In `pymongo` you have to enclose `$elemMatch` in quotes: `mydb.balochistan_uni.find('$elemMatch': ...`.

Answer (score 0):

to filter only disciplines that match your criteria, you have to use aggregation framework. One way to do this :

```
 mydb.balochistan_uni.aggregate(
    [

        {
            $redact: {
                            $cond: {
                                  if: { $or:[
                                    {$eq: [ "$discipline_name", "Computer Science" ] },
                                    { "$ifNull": [ "$disciplines",  false] }
                                    ]},
                                  then: "$$DESCEND",
                                  else: "$$PRUNE"
                                }
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$disciplines",

            }
        },
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot: "$disciplines"
            }
        },
    ]
);
```

will return :

```
{ 
    "discipline_name" : "Computer Science", 
    "degree_Name" : "BS", 
    "duration" : "4 Years", 
    "Fee_per_Year" : "NA", 
    "admission_date" : "31-01-2018", 
    "Last_Merit" : "NA"
}
{ 
    "discipline_name" : "Computer Science", 
    "degree_Name" : "BS", 
    "duration" : "4 Years", 
    "Fee_per_Year" : "15000", 
    "admission_date" : "14-09-2018", 
    "Last_Merit" : "NA"
}
```

Comment: i want my output to be only consisting of matched dictionary for e.g.
 {
            "discipline_name" : "Computer Science", 
            "degree_Name" : "BS", 
            "duration" : "4 Years", 
            "Fee_per_Year" : "15000", 
            "admission_date" : "14-09-2018", 
            "Last_Merit" : "NA"
        }
not the whole info including university inforamtion
can you plz help me

Comment: Does it match your needs?